# XCode 7 (upgrade from XCode 5), setting int variables on self is behaving strangely

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode5, xcode7

So I'm taking a project from Xcode 5 and porting it to XCode 7. I'm running into some very strange behavior where essentially I have a class that sets an integer instance variable on itself, and when it does, for some reason the integer value gets garbled (as if there's some strange pointer referencing going on).

Here's a basic gist of the code

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject 
{
    int myValue;
    NSString *myString;
}

+ (id) defaultMyClass
- (BOOL) setUpMyValues

@end


@implementation MyClass

+ (id) defaultMyClass 
{
    return [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [ super init ];
    myString = nil;
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) setUpMyValues
{
    myValue = 21;
    myString = @"real string value";
    return true;
}
```

Going through lldb, what I end up with is

```
> p myValue 
> (int) $1 = 3285152 // This number changes on each run
> p myString
> (NSString *) $3 = 0x003220a0 class name = MyClass
> p self 
> (MyClass *) $5 = 0x0013a6f0
> p self[0]
> (MyClass) $6 = {}
```

I think the values I'm getting for self and self[0] are related to the issue. Looking at the list of variables in the debugger, expanding the contents of self just provides [0], so it looks kind of like this:

```
[A] self = (MyClass *) 0x13a6f0
   [0] (MyClass)
     //Nothing further expands.
```

I really have no idea what could be causing this issue. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: When you look at these values in lldb, where are you setting the breakpoint?  I don't see where `setUpMyValues` is called.

Comment: @i_am_jorf on return true.

Comment: Try `print (int) myValue`. I've seen the debugger get confused sometimes. Also, is this a debug build or a release build? If a release build with optimization on, the debugger often prints incorrect information.

Comment: print (int) myValue returns the same. This is actually running on a test build in debug mode (so through unit tests via XCTest)